# How to disable apps from restarting after Windows shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, reboot

I have a script that run a shutdown command on my Windows 10 computer every night (`shutdown /s /t 300`, so no `/f` there). Sometimes I would have things open like Chrome, Explorer and Spotify etc. How do I stop Windows 10 from restarting these apps at next startup?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fully shutdown the system, without any delay / prompts you need to use the -f flag for a forceful shutdown, this will stop any programs that are being used in admin mode and it stops all services.
If you can try changing that script then

change that shutdown command to

```
shutdown /f /s /t 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. "How do I stop Windows 10 from restarting these apps at next startup? "